# Remove multiple contact photos at once

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts

I made a mistake of using Micopi, an app that changes all of the contact's photos on the phone. This got synced back with my contact list on Google. I'd like to know if there is a way to do a multi-edit on all of my contacts to remove their photos from my contact database at once instead of manually going through my list.

edit: Device: OnePlus One, running Sultan's CM12.1 ROM, rooted

Comment: Is the device rooted? Which device is it? The photos most likely would be stored in /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/photos

Comment: @Firelord Yes, it is.

Comment: @Firelord Device info added to original post, there are 6 files in the directory which don't seem to be pictures. http://i.imgur.com/w7Dn8Q5.png